# Database table design for ratings table and review table with ratings

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have a table `tc_res_rating` that looks like this:

```
| user_id | res_id | rating | review_id | post_date (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)|
|    1    |    13  |  4.0   |    3      |  2016-12-14 17:02:12         |
|    2    |    6   |  3.5   |   NULL    |  2016-12-19 20:55:24         |
```

and another table `tc_res_reviews` that look like :

```
| review_id | res_id | user_id |    review    |     date_created    |
|     3     |   13   |    1    | [BLOB - 4 B] | 2016-12-14 17:02:12 |
```

Users can create ratings for restaurant without reviews,

so the rating data will be inserted directly into `tc_res_rating` with `review_id` NULL.

Users can also insert review for the restaurant with a rating linked to that review,

so the review is inserted into `tc_res_reviews` and the rating inserted into `tc_res_rating` with `review_id`

Is this the right table schema for this type of scenario?

Comment: Looks OK. Given that you already have a restaurant id and a user id in both tables, the review is seems redundant

Comment: @yeh What are your primary keys? Can a review exist without a rating?

Comment: I don't think you need to have two tables, you can use one table that should also include the 'review' column. If somebody does't want to write a review, keep it NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is for sure that to remove repeating columns(res_id and user_id) from tc_res_reviews table.

I may remove tc_res_reviews table completely as we can save review itself in tc_res_rating table. I believe one user can give review a restaurant once only.

Column review can be allowed NULL so users who want to just rate restaurant can save rating for restaurant.